# On Windows, do I need to give any special permissions to my web server user to run a script created by Administrator?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, php, web-server

I'm trying to run a PHP script from the webserver that executes other scripts and programs. When I run it manually, everything works fine, but when I run it from the webserver, it doesn't seem to execute it, though I get no error messages. Could be a permissions issue? If so, how can I fix it? If not, well, how do I fix it?

Comment: Which web server software?

Answer (score 0):

If the errorlog shows nothing of value i usually resort to procmon wich should give you a good hint to find the problem. just start procmon, execute the script through apache2, stop procmon and search for the scriptname or filter accordingly.

- http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645